# how to integrate bot into skype

Tags: .net, bots

Can anyone help me how to integrate bot created using LUIS.ai into Skype?

Added all details in Web.Config

```
 <appSettings>
<!-- update these with your BotId, Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
<add key="BotId" value="BOTB2018" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="********-****-****-****-999****65b35" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="#############)?!umhA59;" />
```

I created BOT using LUIS.ai and .NET application and its working fine, I tested using `botframework-emulator` and getting the response.

Install certificate also on IIS and converted the website into https:// and now I want to integrate my BOT into Skype.

Tried to follow below URL but not getting any help, can someone please help me on this?

Comment: The link is missing.

Comment: here is the url:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0